# Select different min dates BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[image: Input and expected output]

I have a table with different values in BigQuery and I want to select the min or the max of these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min/max with group by to get min or max date per ID group

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DATE) AS MIN_DATE, MAX(DATE) AS MAX_DATE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```